# Throwing anonymous exception subclass

Tags: c++

I was playing with c++ exceptions and I've tried throwing an anonymous exception like this:

```
throw class : public std::exception
{
    virtual const char *what() const noexcept
    {
        return "Custom exception";
    }
} ex;
```

However I'm getting the following error when trying to compile:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘class’
throw class : public std::exception
      ^
```

My compiler is gcc 5.2.1 on Linux x86_64.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a class in a throw statement.  Declare the class first <del>(anonymously if you like, naming it via a typedef)</del>, then you can throw it.

Better is to name the exception class, but put it in the nameless namespace:

```
namespace {
   class LocalException : public std::exception {
       const char *what() const noexcept override {
           return "Custom exception";
       }
    };
 }
    ....
    throw LocalException();
```

or, if you insist, you can create an object of anonymous class, and throw that.

```
static class : public std::exception {
   const char *what() const noexcept override {
       return "Custom exception";
   }
 } LocalExceptionObject;
    ....
    throw LocalExceptionObject;
```

**Edit** If you create a typedef, somebody can copy it, and it names the same class.  You have to create an object of the anonymous class, and then nobody can name it.

Having said that, I don't think having anonymous things is useful.  Far better to declare the class in a nameless namespace (so you know it is private), and just use it.

Comment: I've found typedef to be optional

Comment: There is no point for the typedef syntax. It is just another way of making the class not anonymous.

Comment: Without the typedef, you create a single object of the anonymous type, which you can then throw (without the parens).  With the typedef, you create a class, and then throw a new instance of it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It's still sort-of anonymous.  Specifically, that class cannot be referred to outside the current translation unit.  Perhaps I don't understand why you would want a completely unnameable class.

Comment: there however seems to be a problem, the exception is caught, however the message is not "Custom exception" as expected

Comment: What is the message then?

Comment: @MartinBonner If it has a name, it isn't anonymous. My point is that the typedef syntax doesn't change anything.

Comment: the text is `std::exception`apparently the function does not get overloaded

Comment: Did you use the "override" keyword rather than "virtual" - that will give a compiler error if what isn't overriding a function in the base.  Other than that, I suggest making the class named to start with, and make sure that works, and then making it nameless afterwards.

Comment: @juanchopanza: With the typedef, no client code in other files can catch exceptions of that type.  They can only catch the base exception.

Comment: @tofifee: How are you *catching* the exception?  As "const std::exception e", or "const std::exception& e".  The former will create a copy of just the base class (which will have the base what).  The latter should use the overridden what.

Comment: @MartinBonner They can if it is in a header file. The typedef syntax makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: yes, I did try to catch it, that's how I got the message.

Comment: I know you caught it, but *how* did you catch it?  What was the text of the catch statement?

Comment: @juanchopanza:  Hmm.  I think you are right.  If somebody copies the typedef statement, they will be naming the same type - time for some edits.

Comment: `catch(std::exception e){std::cout<<e.what();}`

Comment: So that's your problem.  e is not the object that was thrown, it is a copy of *just the base class*.  You need to catch as `catch(const std::exception& e)`.  Note the *&*

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer per-se, but some important information what will help you going forward:

First, throwing an anonymous exception is unlikely to be useful. Exceptions are caught by their type. If you can't name the type, you can't catch the exception explicitly - only by its base, in which case you may as well have just thrown the base.

Second (and this is important):

There's rarely a good reason to derive from `std::exception` directly. You should derive from one of the exception types defined in `<stdexcept>`

these are:

`std::runtime_error` - indicating that some runtime condition makes it impossible to perform the service *at the moment* (such as a missing file).

`std::logic_error` - indicating that what was attempted will never be possible and the program is fundamentally in error in a way that could not be detected at compile time.

Handy reference here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept